# Need help in integrating role-based access control with MSAL authentication in Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, role-based-access-control

It's my first time trying to build a role based access control, but I'm facing some problems and would appreciate any kind of help.
I've got a User who's authentication is handled through MSAL in the frontend.
However the roles of a user should be (due to safety reasons) stored only in a database. Is there any kind of way I can load the user from my database and get him into the security context?

I've already looked in some tutorials but they all use the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter that is no longer in use (as far as I know) and I also created a CustomUserDetailsSerive to load the User from my database, so I just need to find a way to load the User into a Security Context.
In addition what kind of spring security filter chain would you recommend to use in my case?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.